# Nuget Connection failure

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore, nuget-server

I have set up a private feed for nuget on our TFS server, using the nuget server, package. This has been successfully running for some time, but now I need to move it to a new server. (TFS Consolidation)

On the new server I can use the settings to point to the new server. I can get the packages to show up in the UI, and in a list if I run nuget list -source but when I attempt to install a package I get an error

Unable to connect to the remote server

from the command line I get:

Install-Package : Unable to connect to the remote serverAt line:1 char:1
•INstall-package BrXXXXXXXs.GlobalConstants -source http://tfs.brXXXXXXXs.c ...
•
◦CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
◦FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I have compared the 2 end points and I do not see what is different. I can access both thru a browser.